# JAVA - Make a Method that Reads a List

Tags: java, arrays, list, methods

I made a bunch of methods and encountered this part of the question:

***"Test your methods in a program and include a method that reads a list, terminated by -999, into an array."***

I am not sure what to do on this part and hopefully someone can show me and explain how I can do this. Here is my Code:

*(NOTE: the comment showing "4-Termination Method" section is empty. That is where I'm trying to make the code)*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem3 {
    //1-MAXIMUM METHOD//
    public static int max(int[] arr)
    {
        int tmpMax = arr[0];
            for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i] > tmpMax)
                {
                    tmpMax = arr[i];
                }
            }
            return tmpMax;
    }
    //2-MINIMUM METHOD//
    public static int min(int[] arr)
    {
        int tmpMin = arr[0];
            for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i] < tmpMin)
                {
                    tmpMin = arr[i];
                }
            }
            return tmpMin;
    }
    //3-MIN-MAX METHOD//
    public static int[] maxMin(int[] arr)
    {
        int[] myArray = new int [2];
        myArray[0] = min(arr);
        myArray[1] = max(arr);
        return myArray;
    }
    //4-TERMINATION METHOD//
    public static int termination(int[] arr)
    {

    }
    //5-MAIN-METHOD//
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b, c, d, e;
        System.out.println("Input the Numbers: ");
        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();
        c = input.nextInt();
        d = input.nextInt();
        e = input.nextInt();
        int[] test = {a, b, c, d, e};
        System.out.println("The Maximum Number is: " + min(test));
        System.out.println("The Minimum Number is: " + max(test));
        int [] x = maxMin(test);
        System.out.println("Min: " + x[0]);
        System.out.println("Max: " + x[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the requirement is, but I'm guessing it wants you to repeatedly read from `System.in` and place each integer value you read into an array until the value -999 is encountered. I would also guess that the -999 should not be placed in the array as it is the terminator.

Comment: As far as the "Test your methods in a program" it just means you should write some code that calls your other code and verifies that it works correctly. For example, you might have a method `testMin` that calls `min` and checks its output against your expectations.

Comment: So from here I should use If-Statements, right? To check if any of the input numbers encounters -999?

Comment: Well, you could use an `if` statement, but you should think about which programming control structure you should use to repeat a section of code until a condition is met.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, please see the update to the answer I wrote yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT #1:**

It has been nearly 24 hours so I'll give you some more hints regarding the requirement to "include a method that reads a list..."

You want to use a loop that ends when the user inputs a value of -999. You also have to consider that the requirement is to read the values into an array so that means you will have to resize the array each time through the loop.

So your logic would go something like this:

1. Get the first integer from `System.in` and store it in a variable
2. Initialize an array to hold the input values, initial length 0
3. Begin looping until the variable from #1 equals -999

   a) Resize the array from #2

   b) Add the integer to the resized array

   b) Read the next integer from `System.in` and store in the same variable as #1

**END EDIT #1**

I don't want to give too much away too soon - see [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). So please see my comment regarding the requirement "include a method that reads a list...".

I will give you a short example of how to test your code "in a program":

```
public class TestProblem3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        testMin();
    }

    public static void testMin(){
         int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
         int minValue = Problem3.min(data);
         if( minValue != 1 )
             System.err.println("FAILURE expected 1, but actual value is "+minValue);

         data = new int[]{-1,2,3,4,5};
         minValue = Problem3.min(data);
         if( minValue != -1 )
             System.err.println("FAILURE expected -1, but actual value is "+minValue);

         //More tests here!
    }

    //More test methods here!
}
```

If you're really ambitious you could learn about [JUnit](http://junit.org) and/or other testing frameworks (like [TestNG](http://testng.org))